# Masked functions when a package is loaded, but not reciprocal?

Tags: r, package, masking

I had the `dplyr` package loaded when I loaded the `stringi` package.  This message appeared (I dropped a couple of lines re ggplot2 being masked for %+%).

```
require(stringi)
Loading required package: stringi

Attaching package: ‘stringi’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    %>%
```

When I returned to using dplyr, I reloaded it.

```
require(dplyr)
```

Why did that last call not warn me that %>% is masked from stringi?

More generally, if you don't remember to reload a package (and presumably restore its use of some function masked by another package, how do you figure out the masking?

Comment: If you call `library` or `require` for an already loaded package, the package is not reloaded. Since masking only occurs when a package is loaded, `%>%` will not be masked when you try to reload `dplyr`. If you need to refer to `dplyr`'s `%>%` function, you can use `dplyr::'%>%'` or make sure you're loading `dplyr` after `stringi`.

Comment: I would just not try to figure it out, and open a fresh R session. And maybe re-name some functions that do different things but have the same name. Did you unload and detach both packages first?

Comment: @RichardScriven.  Good point.  I did not detach stringi, which I assume would have unmasked %>% for the already loaded dplyr.  I have also found that the reorder function I use so much in ggplot gets masked.  I add stats:: and all is well.  How can I find what package has masked reorder()?

Comment: you figure out the masking by the order of the packages in `search()`, or just type `\`%>%\`` and see what the code looks like or which namespace it resides in, or `environment(\`%>%\`)`

Comment: @tkmckenzie: if you put this in an answer I will accept it.  I just realized I have not done anything except learn from this.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can reload `dplyr` using the [devtools](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/devtools/docs/reload) package.

```
library(devtools)
reload(inst("dplyr"))
```